# Regex expression to extract numbers from "12234 x 344 x 3545"

Tags: regex

Need a regex expression to extract first, second and third set of numbers from below examples

- 522×318×495mm K
- 365×320×320mm A
- 465×235×145
- 480×250×465mm
- 420×235×145mm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you ask for:

```
/(\d+)×(\d+)×(\d+)/
```

You can play with the pattern and get nice explanation what is captured [here](https://regexr.com/47u03).

The numbers will be in the capturing group, depending on which tools you use, there will be different way of getting to the results. For example in Perl:

```
perl -n -e '/^(\d+)×(\d+)×(\d+)/ && print "$1 $2 $3"'
```

Comment: Instead of "x" can it be any non-numeral character?

Comment: (\d+)[^0-9](\d+)[^1-9](\d+)


Now need to remove spaces

Comment: Exactly and if you want to accept one or more of such characters, you can do: `(\d+)[^0-9]+(\d+)[^1-9]+(\d+)` - this would also match "123xxx234xx567".

Comment: how do you match 1234   xx  2333 xx x  4444
So first we need to trim all spaces

Comment: The expression `(\d+)[^0-9]+(\d+)[^1-9]+(\d+)` that I posted in the previous comment also matches spaces, so it works as it is.

The key is `[^0-9]+` which essentially means "anything but number, one or more characters" so this also includes spaces and such.

Comment: How can we also include decimals?

Comment: Just match dot and number. /(\d+\.\d+)×(\d+\.\d+)×(\d+\.\d+)/  Notice that the dot is escaped, because otherwise it means "any character", so by escaping it you explicitly match an dot.